# awk gensub got the wrong part of matches

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I want to extract "yy a1 b1" with the awk expression

```
echo "xx yy [a1 b1] / zz [a2 b2]/" | awk '{p=gensub(/.*\[([a-z0-9 ]+)\].*/,"\\1",1); print $2,p}'
```

but always get "yy a2 b2". I might work out a solution, but just curious the problem of above expression. The [prototype of gensub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) is:

`gensub(regexp, replacement, how [, target])`

why the specified 'how' not take effect?

Comment: The point is that the first `.*` matches the whole string and then backtracks thus making the regex engine match the last occurrence of the remaining subpattern. Try the [`/[^][]*\[([a-z0-9 ]+)\].*/`](https://ideone.com/lT720m) regex if you plan to match up to the first `[...]`.

Comment: Why do you expect the output to be `yy a1 b1`? That's unclear. If you just want to remove the `[]` then use `tr -d [] < input`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: be careful, awk doesn't use a backtracking engine, but the first `.*` takes the largest match by default.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte If you know a better term here, please supply.

Comment: That should be the reason, thanks! @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: you can remember two rules: quantifiers are greedy, and the pattern is evaluated from left to right.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I know that by heart for years. If you know a good reference on how POSIX regex engine *internally* matches greedy subpatterns, it would be a much more helpful comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Is this case, for what reason do you write that `.*` matches the whole string and then backtracks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the first `.*` as many chars as possible, thus making the regex engine match the last occurrence of the remaining subpatterns.

You may use the following solution:

```
/[^][]*\[([a-z0-9 ]+)\].*/
```

where `[^][]*` matches any 0 or more chars other than `]` and `[`, thus, allowing the regex engine to stop right before the first `[...]`

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/lT720m)